# Is bouldering moderate or vigorous intensity exercise?

Tags: met, bouldering

I'm considering incorporating bouldering into my fitness routine. I have no experience bouldering or climbing, my other fitness activities are running.

The U.S. Department of Health and Human Service's [recommendations](https://health.gov/paguidelines/second-edition/) are based on whether an activity is either moderate or vigorous intensity.  Moderate activities are done at 3.0 - 5.9 METs, while vigorous activities are 6.0 METS are above. Qualitatively, they describe moderate activities as ones where people can talk while they perform them.

For the purpose of the DHHS guidelines should I consider bouldering a moderate or vigorous intensity activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not going to like this answer, but... it depends.

Regardless of the intensity level, you should definitely add bouldering into your fitness routine because of the myriad of benefits to both physical and [psychological](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/05/170525161321.htm) health.

As to your actual question, the MET scale is relative to your personal fitness level, so as a runner, a nice 20 minute jog for you might be a moderate activity, for me, it would probably rate as intense.

For bouldering (and climbing) you need to take into account three main factors, experience, bodyweight and the route you're attempting.

Firstly because, as you say, you've never done any form of climbing before, you'll find everything new; your body won't know how to position itself (it's all in the hips!), you won't know how to place your feet (gently) or grip with your fingers (as loose as possible), so all routes you try, regardless of length (bouldering routes are traditionally shorter and harder than climbing routes) you'll be exerting a lot more energy than someone who has several years experience (watch a 70 year old man with a slight pot belly flow up a route you've just spent 30 minutes fighting with, it's a humbling experience).

Secondly, if you're heavier, it's going to be harder. Power to weight ratio is important, but generally speaking, shorter, lighter climbers have it easier than heavier, taller ones (short people will argue this until they're blue in the face, but shorter people can get stronger in order to make stretched out moves, taller people can't get shorter).

Lastly, the route itself is important. If you're climbing on large holds on a slab (a wall that leans away from you), then even if you've never climbed before and you're carrying a few extra pounds, it's not likely to be that difficult. If, however, you're climbing a long route under a roof, and you're an experienced, slender power house of a climber, it can still get your heart pumping because of the body tension you're having to maintain for a prolonged period.

Unfortunately, because of these three things, only you can really answer this question.

One thing I would suggest though, with most new climbers, there's always the urge to push yourself and climb the hardest route you can from the get go (something that would be considered vigorous exercise). I'd recommend against this for a while. Try and stick with a more moderate activity level of bouldering for a few months after you start, the reason being it can take your body, particularly the fingers, a while to get used to some of the unique stressors involved in climbing. Enjoy the process of learning to move in an unfamiliar way, practicing on routes you can already do to make them smoother and less of an effort. Think of it as a form of moving meditation.

Comment: Actually, I like this answer quite a lot. Thanks! However, I thought METs were an absolute unit of measure - something like how much energy is expended per hour on some activity.

Comment: @indigochild From a PDF on the link you provided "Absolute rates of energy expenditure during physical activity are commonly described as light, moderate, or
vigorous intensity. Energy expenditure is expressed by multiples of the metabolic equivalent of task (MET),
where 1 MET is the rate of energy expenditure while sitting at rest." so yes, but...

Comment: Maybe saying it's relative to your fitness wasn't the right way of phrasing it. If you're doing an activity you haven't done before, then your body won't be as efficient at it, and efficiency, or lack there of, is what makes activities appear easy or hard. A 20 minute jog for me would be intense because I don't run, it's a completely foreign activity for me. I can't just ease into a particular stride or rhythm and breathing pattern, I have to keep thinking about what I'm doing. Climbing though, I can switch off and just move along or up the wall without having to think too hard, you can't.

Comment: So, I would expend a lot more energy than you on a jog, and you would expend a lot more energy than me on a climb, but we both might expend the same amount of energy sitting on the sofa watching Netflix. Make sense?